# How to send an ACTION to irc with python & sockets

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I'm trying to send an action to irc with python and sockets (/me blah) but I can't figure out how.  I'm pretty sure my code is completely wrong.  Here it is:

```
if text.find(":hit") != -1:
        irc.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :\x01ACTIONhits " + str(text.split(" ")[4]) + "!\x01")
```

But when I execute it, it just prints this:

[image: The bot's name is hitter]

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: Syntax looks fine maybe the problem is the text you are splitting?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your screenshot, the `!` at the end is missing too.
So, `text.split(" ")[4]` is likely to contain a line break character, which breaks the current message there and tells the server that what comes after is another command.

Try replacing it with: `text.split(" ")[4].replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')`

and you should also send `\r\n` at the end of the message (unless the `send()` function already does it), so the server understands the command ends there.

Comment: My code looks like this `irc.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :\x01ACTIONhits " + str(text.split(" ")[4].replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')) + "!\x01\r\n")` and it does this `* Received a CTCP ACTIONhits me! from Hitter (to #Prince)`  I'm not sure what I did wrong.  A little help?

Comment: Add a space after `ACTION`